# Celery monitoring on Heroku

Tags: heroku, celery

I have a worker process in a Heroku app that runs Celery (`celery worker --app=myapp`). What should I use to monitor workers? Is there something built-in in Django? Or is there some 3rd-party service?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Flower](https://github.com/mher/flower), a real-time web based monitor and administration tool for Celery. [This repo](https://github.com/jorilallo/celery-flower-heroku) contains a guide on how to run it on Heroku.

Configure the app by providing your broker url and a password for logging into Flower:

```
heroku config:set BROKER_URL=redis://...
heroku config:set FLOWER_BASIC_AUTH="username:password"
```

Comment: [Here's another repo](https://github.com/jpadilla/heroku-flower) which makes deploying a Celery Flower instance to Heroku a one-click adventure! Click the Deploy to Heroku button under the giant celery photo, fill in your broker URL and set a basic auth username/password. Cheers

Comment: The repos mentioned above are not working. [This repo](https://github.com/iyanuashiri/celery-flower-heroku) works by fixing the issues with the above-mentioned repos and implementing a deploy to Heroku button