# How to monitor celery logs in heroku

Tags: heroku, celery, flower

I want to monitor celery logs from an app in Heroku. I did some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177485/celery-monitoring-on-heroku) and found a couple of [repos](https://github.com/iyanuashiri/celeroku) that deploy a new heroku app which uses flower to monitor.

Problem:
I followed those instructions and deployed a new app to heroku but I get this error message:

```
2023-08-03T11:09:17.312149+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 88, in <module>
2023-08-03T11:09:17.312150+00:00 app[web.1]:     from tornado import httputil
2023-08-03T11:09:17.312150+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/httputil.py", line 107, in <module>
2023-08-03T11:09:17.312151+00:00 app[web.1]:     class HTTPHeaders(collections.MutableMapping):
2023-08-03T11:09:17.312151+00:00 app[web.1]:                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-08-03T11:09:17.312151+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
2023-08-03T11:09:17.436513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-08-03T11:09:17.458578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-08-03T11:11:21.923503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=celery-logger-4bd8f3ddc739.herokuapp.com request_id=50c72c4a-c22e-4801-8b4b-b7ec1eeaf3f2 fwd="86.14.252.189" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-08-03T11:11:23.115128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=celery-logger-4bd8f3ddc739.herokuapp.com request_id=8c2c0a9a-3632-4b80-a10a-9ca568fd0fc9 fwd="86.14.252.189" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Not sure what I have done wrong? Please bear in mind that I'm not a software developer.